# How to put Indicator no image flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, carousel

how to put on image like the design. I was learn on youtube but tutorial have only outside, I try to use Carousel_Pro but it's can't use because it's not nullSafety .

```
Center(
                      child: CarouselSlider(
                    carouselController: _carouselController,
                    options: CarouselOptions(
                        initialPage: 0,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.23,
                        viewportFraction: 1.0,
                        enlargeCenterPage: false,
                        onPageChanged: (index, reason) =>
                            setState(() => activeIndex = index)
                        // autoPlay: false,
                        ),
                    items: imageList
                        .map((item) => Container(
                              child: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                      height:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                              1,
                                      width:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
                                      child: Image.network(
                                        item,
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        height:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                                1,
                                      ))),
                            ))
                        .toList(),
                  )),
                  buildIndicator(),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Stack` widget : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

It will help you to stack widget one on another instead of one under another

Comment: it's work thank you :>

Answer (score 0):

```
Center(
                      child: CarouselSlider(
                    carouselController: _carouselController,
                    options: CarouselOptions(
                        initialPage: 0,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.23,
                        viewportFraction: 1.0,
                        enlargeCenterPage: false,
                        onPageChanged: (index, reason) =>
                            setState(() => activeIndex = index)
                        // autoPlay: false,
                        ),
                    items: imageList
                        .map((item) => Container(
                              child: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                      height:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                              1,
                                      width:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
                                      child: Image.network(
                                        item,
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        height:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                                1,
                                      ))),
                            ))
                        .toList(),
                  )),
                imageList.lenght> 0?  buildIndicator() : SizedBox(),
```